# How do I create environment-specific cookies that don't persist through different environments in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, httpcookie

So right now I set up an application cookie in `Startup.cs` that is specific to whatever environment that I'm currently in (Development, Staging, Production).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ..snip..

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = $".example_auth_{_env.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}";
        options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    });

    // ..snip..
}
```

This works great. If I'm in Development, the cookie "`.example_auth_development`" gets created, etc.

However, if I switch to a different environment (without logging out of the original environment) - in this case let's say I go from Development to Staging, and I already have a `Development cookie`. When I launch the Staging environment, I get issued a `Staging cookie`, but the `Development cookie` is still there.

Is there a way to avoid having multiple environment cookies at once? Ideally, I would like it so if you were in Development, you would ONLY have a `Development cookie`, and so on.

Comment: Are you doing all of these "environments" on localhost? If so, cookies are domain based so they're going to stick to the domain in the browser until you clear them.

Comment: @RyanMendoza Ahh, that makes much more sense. So do you think it's not even worth having different environment cookies? I only did that so that when I was logging in and out of my Development site, that it wouldn't log me out of my Production site and vice versa.

Comment: It should be fine to not worry about putting your environment prefix/suffix in the cookie name. They won't cross over anyway unless you host your environments like site.com/dev and site.com/staging.